# Slow data HDD effect on system?

Tags: windows-7

My question is relatively simple I hope.  I have an otherwise fast system (3570k, SSD, 8gb RAM) with all of my data on a slower platter drive.  If I replaced it with a faster drive would there be a difference in system performance or would the difference be minimal given that my OS is already installed to the SSD?

Comment: You'll need to define "slower"/"faster" drive, difference in system performance you want to see and what kind of data you are talking about and what do you do with it.

Comment: Performance will be effected if the read speed will be increase and read/write speed of a fast drive will do this. But your question is not clear so much so its hard to say exactly what you are asking about.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by faster/slower you mean read/write speed...

Yes, in general you should see some difference in system performance in that writing/reading data to/from the data drive should speed up. It will not have a marked difference on the other functionality of your system.

I should add that any programs that read/write from/to that data drive *may* show performance improvements with a "faster drive"

You have not given enough info for much more specificity.